# Website form login using Python urllib2

Tags: python, urllib2

I've breen trying to learn to use the urllib2 package in Python. I tried to login in as a student (the left form) to a signup page for maths students: http://reg.maths.lth.se/. I have inspected the code (using Firebug) and the left form should obviously be called using POST with a key called `pnr` whose value should be a string 10 characters long (the last part can perhaps not be seen from the HTML code, but it is basically my social security number so I know how long it should be). Note that the `action` in the header for the appropriate POST method is another URL, namely http://reg.maths.lth.se/login/student.

I tried (with a fake `pnr` in the example below, but I used my real number in my own code).

```
import urllib
import urllib2

url = 'http://reg.maths.lth.se/'
values = dict(pnr='0000000000')
data = urllib.urlencode(values)
req = urllib2.Request(url,data)
resp = urllib2.urlopen(req)
page = resp.read()

print page
```

While this executes, the print is the source code of the original page [http://reg.maths.lth.se/](http://reg.maths.lth.se/.), so it doesn't seem like I logged in. Also, I could add any key/value pairs to the values dictionary and it doesn't produce any error, which seems strange to me.

Also, if I go to the page http://reg.maths.lth.se/login/student, there is clearly no POST method for submitting data.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Just a suggestion to look at the excellent http://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/ library.

Comment: @gahooa Thanks for the suggestion! I might have a look at it, but I have a feeling my problem is due to some misunderstanding on my part of the HTML code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you would inspect what request is sent to the server when you enter the number and submit the form, you would notice that it is a *POST request* with `pnr` and `_token` parameters:

[image]

You are missing the `_token` parameter which you need to extract from the HTML source of the page. It is a hidden `input` element:

```
<input name="_token" type="hidden" value="WRbJ5x05vvDlzMgzQydFxkUfcFSjSLDhknMHtU6m">
```

I suggest looking into tools like [`Mechanize`](http://wwwsearch.sourceforge.net/mechanize/), [`MechanicalSoup`](https://github.com/hickford/MechanicalSoup) or [`RoboBrowser`](https://github.com/jmcarp/robobrowser) that would ease the form submission. You may also parse the HTML with an HTML parser, like `BeautifulSoup` yourself, extract the token and send via `urllib2` or [`requests`](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/):

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

PNR = "00000000"

url = "http://reg.maths.lth.se/"
login_url = "http://reg.maths.lth.se/login/student"
with requests.Session() as session:
    # extract token
    response = session.get(url)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(response.content, "html.parser")
    token = soup.find("input", {"name": "_token"})["value"]

    # submit form
    session.post(login_url, data={
        "_token": token,
        "pnr": PNR
    })

    # navigate to the main page again (should be logged in)
    response = session.get(url)

    soup = BeautifulSoup(response.content, "html.parser")
    print(soup.title)
```

Comment: Do you mean that `values = dict(pnr='0000000000',_token='WRbJ5x05vvDlzMgzQydFxkUfcFSjSLDhknMHtU6m')` should do the trick? I tried it and it doesn't change anything, that is 'print page' still gives the source code of the Host page.

Comment: @AlexandreVandermonde updated with a sample `requests` + `BeautifulSoup` code. Hope that helps.

Comment: Alright, thank you very much! I'll download the extra pachages and try it out. However, I would still like to understand why my code fails.

Comment: @AlexandreVandermonde sure, the key thing is that you were missing the token parameter. But, the problem was also that you needed to maintain a web-scraping session to keep and share the cookies among the requests - this is what the requests package and the requests.Session are handling in the example. Also, after submitting the post request, you would then need to get the main page again..sorry, if this is too much information, but I think this is how it works in this particular case and the code sample in the answer should work.

Comment: I just tried the code, and got a 405 Method not allowed error.

Comment: @AlexandreVandermonde my bad, the URL where we post is different, updated.

Comment: I actually don't think that I'm supposed to go back to the main page. I guess I should have mentioned this, but when I logged in manually, I was directed to the  http://reg.maths.lth.se/login/student page.

Comment: @AlexandreVandermonde may be it will work without going to the main page again, please try, I don't have a valid pnr to test..

Comment: I get the same error with the updated code, even if I use my valid pnr.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/102940/discussion-between-alecxe-and-alexandre-vandermonde).

Comment: Hi again! As I wrote in the chat, perhaps after you had left, the code still doesn't seem to work. I haven't been able to figure out why.

Comment: @AlexandreVandermonde Sorry, was AFK yesterday. okay, please post a separate requests/BeautifulSoup specific question and post your complete current code with the current behavior and the desired one. This way more people can look at your problem and perhaps help. Please throw me a link here too. Thanks!

Comment: Okay, thanks for the suggestion! Here is the new question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35297316/trouble-with-requests-beautiful-soup